# Como fazer o menu ir para o topo usando Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Vejo em muitos sites [como este](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/woocommerce_55230/portfolio/) que ao iniciar a rolagem o Menu vai pro topo e quando está no topo ele fica no seu lugar de origem (Como se estivesse flutuando). Como aplico este efeito?

Comment: Quando a rolagem da tela ultrapassar certo limite (aquele que faria o menu ultrapassar o topo da tela) mude a classe da div que contém o menu: 1) faça com que o menu tenha `position: fixed` e `top: 0px`; 2) acrescente (ou faça visível) uma `div` vazia para ocupar o espaço que o menu ocupava (sem isso, a rolagem daria um "salto"). Isso pode ser feito em JS puro, mas talvez o jQuery e/ou o Bootstrap tenham meios mais fáceis de se fazer isso (se até amanhã ninguém der uma resposta melhor, eu coloco mais detalhes do jeito que eu costumo fazer).

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples de adicionar este efeito é através de JavaScript, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

Está resposta tem como base [uma resposta no StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled) internacional. Veja o exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/F4BmP/).